# Is there a way to get Image data when Image is not from the same domain?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-mx, flex-spark

I heard there is a setting that I can change to allow images from remote domains to work? Or is it that I am supposed to call `Security.allowDomain()` method at some point? I would rather just change a setting on the Image component instance if available?

From the documentation:

> SecurityError The `target` object and  all of its child
>   objects do not come from the same domain as the caller, or are not in
>   a content that is accessible to the caller by having called the
>   `Security.allowDomain()` method.

More info:
IIRC there was a property on the `mx:Image` component? I'm using Spark Image component in my project but knowing what that is may help me figure out a solution for the Spark Image.